# End user getting "Missing required element [Email Address]" error on Forcing password reset first logon

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are following Azure B2C sample code [Azure AD B2C: Force password reset first logon](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon) to implement logic to force new local user to reset the password on the first login since we don't want them to use temporary password we generated for them.  It has been working good for us, however recently one of such end users got this error "Missing required element [Email Address]" during reset screen:

[image].

We have been tried to reproduce this and we could not. We are not sure how to investigate this further at this point. Could someone shed some lights on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error is displayed when there is an issue with loading [content definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions) properly declared in the custom policies. I faced similar issue in one of the projects where we used custom policies together with content (HTML, CSS) stored on the Azure Blob Storage.

When the name of a blob folder was called *default*, for some reason the presence of this word in the href tags of the html templates seems to cause the issue. When the folder name was changed to *standard*, it worked without issues.

Make sure that you have proper "load URI" declaration and check the folder name where you store HTML and CSS files.

[image]